# SVG: masking or filtering opacity of elements underneath aka "lowlighting"

Tags: svg, mask, svg-filters, opacitymask

This is a shot in the dark, but maybe there is a way to do it:

I have data laid out in rows and pseudo-columns in an `<svg>`, and I am "lowlighting" inactive pseudo-columns in the pseudo-table. Only one group of contiguous columns is "active" at a time, so it's two lowlighted areas, one on each side of the active columns.

I currently do this with two `<rect>` elements layered on top of the table. These rects are filled with the same color as the background of the body of the web page.  The table itself has no background fill, it is transparent, and the HTML body's background color shows through.  In javascript, I dynamically set the size and position of these two rects, as well as their opacity.  Their opacity is what creates the lowlighting effect.  Instead of highlighting the active columns, I'm lowering the opacity of the data in the inactive columns.

This works, but it prevents me from applying a background texture to the document body.  It is nigh impossible to align patterns between these lowlight rects and the document body.  I am wondering if there is any way to do this with a mask or filter.  I don't see one, but maybe someone else does.

The only way I see to do this is to know more about the inactive columns, and set the opacity for the data inside those columns.  But they are SVG columns, pseudo-columns.  This is sheet music, not numeric/text data, and the columns are measures in the music.  The SVG doesn't delimit the data by measure in a way that let's me isolate all the inactive measures and change their opacity.  That would be a major restructuring effort, and would add significant size and complexity to the project for a relatively minor visual improvement.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're trying to accomplish along with some source code so there's some sense of it

Comment: @MichaelMullany - Here is a codepen that illustrates the effect: https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/mdyJeaz - I want to achieve that effect with the mask not on the path element, but on another rect or path above it in the z-order.  I am now considering doing this with the mask on the element itself and varying the size and offsets in the mask.  That would possibly solve it.  The mask would be an attribute of a group element.

Comment: Here is a slightly more detailed pen: https://codepen.io/sidewayss/pen/BayzPbZ
The sheet music scrolls by translating the <g> element to the left. Is there a way to set units on the gradient and mask so that the mask is relative to the viewBox, not to the translated group? The goal would be for the translate not to translate the mask. The same part of the viewBox would be 100% opacity, not the same part of the path.  Does that make sense?  I can still manage it this way, but it's messier.

Comment: What you're really looking for is backdrop-filter - but this has uneven support particularly in SVG today - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter. Are you trying to get a CSS only solution? Because of course, you can do this with JavaScript easily

Comment: @MichaelMullany - I'm doing it with JavaScript and plan to continue to do it that way.  The SVG is animating and scrolling left to right, and the active area scrolls with it.  There is no CSS-only solution.  I am currently doing with with a pair of rect elements of the same background color on top of the image, varying their opacity.  But that blocks out any underlying pattern too.

I do see a way to do this now, though I might postpone the implementation.  That second codepen is the basic idea.  The gradient stop offset values would be the target of the JavaScript manipulations.

Comment: In playing with that 2nd codepen I see a bug in Firefox!  I'll have to report it now.  In Chrome (win64) the transition to/from full opacity is crisp. In Firefox it fades, even though the stop offsets are identical for the transition points.  Oh well...

Comment: I have submitted the bug at Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1604035   -    for those who are interested.

Comment: @MichaelMullany - I just discovered a use for `backdrop-filter`, and will be giving it a try.  It seems the best solution for a truly translucent custom SVG scrollbar track.  Scrollbars occupy space inside HTML elements, and SVG filters don't support `in` attribute values outside of the SVG.  I couldn't see a way to do this in SVG when the background was unpredictable, or outside of the scope of the `<svg>` itself.  SVG doesn't have `repeat` the way CSS background-image does, and my scrollbar wants to reveal the HTML background-image, same as this original question.